# Adding items to a list by checking if the index exists, and then updating

Tags: python, function

this is a question I have from one of my review packages and I'm pretty stumped. This is the description

"Return a list of m strings, where m is the length of a longest string
in strlist, if strlist is not empty, and the i-th string returned
consists of the i-th symbol from each string in strlist, but only from
strings that have an i-th symbol, in the order corresponding to the
order of the strings in strlist.
Return [] if strlist contains no nonempty strings."

This is the example

> > > transpose(['transpose', '', 'list', 'of', 'strings'])
> > >
> > > ['tlos', 'rift', 'asr', 'nti', 'sn', 'pg', 'os', 's', 'e']

And this is the given format/style you gotta follow

```
# create an empty list to use as a result
# loop through every element in the input list
# loop through each character in the string
# 2 cases to deal with here:
# case 1: the result list has a string at the correct index,
# just add this character to the end of that string
# case 2: the result list doesn't have enough elements,
# need to create a new element to store this character
```

I got upto the "2 cases to deal with here:" part and then I got stuck, this is what I have so far

```
result = []

for index in strlist:
    for char in range (len(index)):
```

Comment: Don't worry about following the "format/style" for now, just try to make something that works first.  Then post it here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this should work:

```
def transpose(strlist):
    # create an empty list to use as a result
    result = []
    # loop through every element in the input list
    for i in range(len(strlist)):
        # loop through each character in the string
        for j in range(len(strlist[i])):
            # 2 cases to deal with here:
            if len(result) > j:
                # case 1: the result list has a string at the correct index,
                # just add this character to the end of that string
                result[j] = result[j] + strlist[i][j]
            else:
                # case 2: the result list doesn't have enough elements,
                # need to create a new element to store this character
                result.append(strlist[i][j])
    return result

print(transpose(['transpose', '', 'list', 'of', 'strings']))
```

it outputs: `['tlos', 'rift', 'asr', 'nti', 'sn', 'pg', 'os', 's', 'e']`

---

there are more pythonic ways to achieve it, but the shown code matches your given format/style